# Why does ngModelCtrl.$dirty not update in my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my Angular app, I'm attempting to build a custom element that contains a simple input field of type text. I have this built here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ulhMuK26JZMfuERG7ch7?p=preview

This works fine. However, when I enter and delete values from the input field, ngModelCtrl.$dirty and ngModelCtrl.$valid never update, though ngModelCtrl.$viewValue does update.

I've been stumped with this all day. Does anyone know why this doesn't update (and how to make it so it does update)?

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <text-field ng-model="myValue"></text-field>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('customControl', []).directive('textField', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      value: '=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<div>' +
              '    <input name="myWidget" ng-model="value" required />' +
              '    <div>ngModel: {{ctrl}}</div>' +
              '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.ctrl = ctrl;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-model` becomes `$dirty` when it is updated from the View - not from the Model - side. Here's a simple example to illustrate:

```
<input ng-model="foo">
<div ng-form="form1">
  <input name="ngModel" ng-model="foo">
</div>
{{form1.ngModel.$dirty}}
```

Typing in the first `<input>` alters the ngModel, but does not set it to `$dirty`. Of course, typing in the second `<input name="ngModel">` does set it to `$dirty`.

And this is what happens in your case. `ngModel` of your directive is only ever updated by changing the model it is bound to, namely, `myValue`, which is bound to `scope.value` inside the directive.

It is important to remember that `ngModel` by itself doesn't set `$dirty` - the directive implementing an input control that makes use of `ngModel`, like the built-in `<input>` controls or your custom input control, would either call `$setDirty` or, more commonly, `$setViewValue` (that triggers `$setDirty` under the covers).

`$setViewValue` is used by input control implementers to set the value on `ngModel` in response to a change in the DOM.

Here's a conceptual example of a custom input control - a simple button that increments a count:

```
.directive("incButton", function() {
  return {
    template: '<button ng-click="inc()">{{val}}</button>',
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      scope.inc = function() {
        scope.val++;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.val);
      };

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        scope.val = ngModel.$isEmpty(ngModel.$viewValue) ? 0 : ngModel.$viewValue;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mw1vEvYbx32TkMASA1q6?p=preview)

To learn how to implement a custom input control, refer to Angular's [documentation for `ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example)

Comment: The ngModelController documentation is actually what I was following. The plunkr is based on the example there. I tried adding `ctrl.$setViewValue(newValue)` in a `$watch` on `value`, but `$dirty` and `$valid` remain unchanged. See http://plnkr.co/edit/FEOIkRJtc73EX16NrLMc?p=preview

Comment: @ChadJohnson, that you because the model has also updated (I presume that you didn't change the binding `value: "=ngModel"`?) - thus the view value is never different than the model. It's not a good idea to bind to `ngModel` - you should just `require` it and interact with it directly

Comment: If I remove `value: "=ngModel"`, what would I bind (ng-model="?") to in the template `<input name="myWidget" ng-model="value" required />`?

Comment: Bind to some internal scope variable and set your directive's `ngModel` accordingly. Or better yet, don't even use `ngModel` in the template because it would interact with a `form` outside of your directive (Angular's bug, in my opinion) - just use `ng-change($event)` and extract the value from the DOM

Comment: @ChadJohnson, updated the answer with an example. (and here's your forked plunker that sets dirty - http://plnkr.co/edit/GA2KjMWt82ZOAiqD1j1E?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome. Very close...$dirty updates, but $valid doesn't seem to change (i.e., if I clear out the input, $valid should be false, as validation fails since the input requires a value).

Comment: @ChadJohnson, that's the beauty of `ng-model` - the user of your directive can put `ng-required` on the `<custom-control>` element and it would just work. Of course, you could also force this behavior by adding a `$validator`.. but that is beyond the scope of the question

Comment: Ah ha! I have to add `required` to the `<text-field>` element usage. Interesting! Makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ChadJohnson, if the answer addressed your question, consider accepting

Comment: Yeah I have it bookmarked and will soon. I want to finish working out the entire problem before I do so though.